# Oracle Report shows invalid characters

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

I have a report which has Thai characters. If I run the report builder's report, the Thai characters display correctly, but if I run the report from the app, the Thai characters display as invalid characters.

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET - AL16UTF16
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET - AL16UTF16
```

in my DB.

Comment: As far as I can tell, report runs on application server (or web logic server) and - therefore - expects that fonts (you used while creating report on your PC in Reports Builder) are also installed on the server. I don't think that NLS database settings matter in this case ...

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot,
Could you please help me to find where I can find those settings

Comment: Fonts are installed on operating system level, which means that you'd have to connect to the server (for example, if it is a MS Windows machine, log in as "administrator") and have a look there. That is, if my assumption is correct.

Comment: What character set is your application, middleware if you use it (e.g. WebLogic, JVM) and the application server OS configured to use? I'd guess at least one layer is using something else - possible even UTF-8 - and needs to be told to expect UTF-16? [This old article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) might be of interest.

Comment: Hi All, 
There is a .env file which holding the language settings inside the middleware folder. I changed the property from Thai_America.UTF8 to Thai_America.TH8TISASCII, now it is working fine.